# Locating third-party Google Docs web apps

Tags: google-workspace, google-docs, security

I got an e-mail from Google today, warning me to "Remove risky access to your data".  According to the security checkup, there are two third-party apps which "have extensive access to [my] personal information and their developers' information hasn't been verified by Google. You should remove their access unless you're sure you trust them."

Both apps have the same name, but the page does not provide anything that allows me to access the app.  Under "app details" it just says "Unverified developer" and what it has access to.  For all I know this could have been something I created for myself and forgot about!  It could also be something useful that I wanted to use and in either case it would be silly to remove access without figuring out what it was.  However, since there appear to be a duplicate, it's possible they are two versions or attempts to do the same thing, so I need to look closely at both of them to figure out which one to get rid of.

I have been searching, but it seems like all my search results only want to tell me how to revoke access, not get more information, However can I locate these apps and figure out exactly what they are so I can make an informed decision?

Comment: Are you using G Suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the scripts/add-ons/web-apps created by yourself by using Google Apps Script should be listed on https://scripts.google.com

If it's not listed there and if you are using a G Suite account, it could be an add-on or app added by the domain administrator

It it's not listed on https://scripts.google.com and it's an add-on, it should be listed on the add-ons menu of the corresponding Google document editors app

- Google Documents
- Google Forms
- Google Sheets
- Google Slides

Comment: Sure enough, they were both under scripts.google.com.  Good to know the other places I could look had it not been there.

Comment: I think the link should be https://script.google.com/... I'm not sure if it's changed since this answer was posted. I don't have enough reputation on webapps to edit :)